# Pass data from main activity to base adapter one

Tags: android, baseadapter

I would like to pass the value of editText1.getText().toString() to the base adapter one in order to compare this value with "num".
¿How can I do it?

Here are my 2 activities:

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

```
private ListView mList;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private MyCustomAdapter mAdapter;
private TCPClient mTcpClient;
private Double comp;


String info; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




   final EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

            editText1.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
                 if (arg1 == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                     Toast.makeText(
                             editText1.getContext()
                             , "Write: " + editText1.getText().toString()
                             , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                             .show();
                     return true;
                 }
                 return false;
                }
            });
     double comp=Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());

    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();





    //relate the listView from java to the one created in xml
    mList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
    mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, arrayList, comp);
    mList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    // connect to the server
    new connectTask().execute("");





}



public class connectTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,TCPClient> {

    @Override
    protected TCPClient doInBackground(String... message) {

        //we create a TCPClient object and
        mTcpClient = new TCPClient(new TCPClient.OnMessageReceived() {
            @Override
            //here the messageReceived method is implemented -->TCPClient.java
            public void messageReceived(String message) {
                //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                publishProgress(message);
            }
        });
        mTcpClient.run();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);


        //in the arrayList we add the messaged received from server
        arrayList.add(values[0]);
        // notify the adapter that the data set has changed. This means that new message received
        // from server was added to the list
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}
```

}

public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<String> mListItems;
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Double comp;



public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList, Double compa){

    mListItems = arrayList;

    comp = compa;
    //get the layout inflater
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    //getCount() represents how many items are in the list
    return mListItems.size();
}


@Override
    //get the data of an item from a specific position
    //i represents the position of the item in the list
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
    //get the position id of the item from the list
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}






@Override


public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


    //check to see if the reused view is null or not, if is not null then reuse it
    if (view == null) {
        view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }

    //get the string item from the position "position" from array list to put it on the TextView
    String stringItem = mListItems.get(position);



    if (stringItem != null) {

        TextView itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_item_text_view);


        if (itemName != null) {
            //set the item name on the TextView
           itemName.setText(stringItem);
            double num=Double.parseDouble(stringItem);
            if (num>comp) {

                itemName.setText(stringItem);

            }


           else {
                itemName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                itemName.setText(stringItem);

           }
        }
    }

    //this method must return the view corresponding to the data at the specified position.
    return view;

}
```

}

Comment: is base adapter is a class or activity?

Comment: public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter

Comment: why you pass data to MyCustomAdapter class?

Comment: Im not sure if i got what you want to know.
Do you have an Activity with a ListView which uses the BaseAdapter and want to pass some data from that Activity to that Adapter? Please note that an Adapter isnt an activity. So "Base Adapter activity" makes no sense at all

Comment: Here is my code added, I hope you will understand what I mean

Answer (score 4):

Add a method `setData()` in your `MyCustomAdapter`, and call it from your main activity.

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Vector listData = null;

    public void setData(Vector data) {
        listData = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to change the list data of the adapter, you may also want to call this.notifyDataSetChanged() in your setData()-Method to reload the view and show the new data immediatly.

Comment: But then how do you reference the setData() method?  You would need an instance of MyCustomAdapter.